# Найти в списке значение по ключу

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, list

Задачка довольно простая, но решить ее не могу. Есть список (lst, например):

```
{'r': '59', 'level': 'Neotem', 'name': 'Crio', 'type': 'Loxer'}
```

Нужно извлечь из него отдельно значения по ключам (r, level, name, type) и присвоить эти значения переменным. Что-то типа:

```
r = lst('r');
lvl = lst('level');
nm = lst('name');
tp = lst('type');
```

Такое можно сделать на Python?

Comment: Вы называете списком (list), то, что судя по Вашему синтаксису, является словарем(dict). Обращайтесь к нему r = lst['r']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта коллекция называется словарь

```
d={'r': '59', 'level': 'Neotem', 'name': 'Crio', 'type': 'Loxer'}
for i in d:
    print(f'Ключ: {i}  Значение:  {d[i]}')
```

---

```
Ключ: r  Значение:  59
Ключ: level  Значение:  Neotem
Ключ: name  Значение:  Crio
Ключ: type  Значение:  Loxer
```